# Getting accurate three-minute time values

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, time

For getting three-minute time values (for example 15.02.2012 07:00:00, 15.02.2012 07:03:00, 15.02.2012 07:06:00,..., 15.02.2012 07:57:00) I use following code:

```
static private DateTime CurrentTime (DateTime now)
        {
            DateTime val;
            val = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0)
                    .AddMinutes(((now.Minute) / 3) * 3 - now.Minute);
            return val;
        }
```

and use this in following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime ts = new DateTime(2012, 2, 15, 08, 1, 0);
            DateTime ts1 = new DateTime(2012, 2, 15, 7, 59, 58);
            Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " is " + CurrentTime(ts).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            Console.WriteLine(ts1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " is " + CurrentTime(ts1).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
        }
```

And output :

```
15.02.2012 08:01:00.000 is 15.02.2012 08:00:00.000
15.02.2012 07:59:58.000 is 15.02.2012 07:57:00.000
```

But in second line I'm get mistake - instead 15.02.2012 07:57:00.000 must be 15.02.2012 08:00:00.000. 
How to fix this mistake? Thanks.

Comment: You code rounds the time down to the nearest 3-minute time value. Is this a problem?

Comment: I don't want to round down nearest third-minute value, I want to round (down or up) to nearest third-minute,  if value between 07:59:30.000 and 08:00:30.000 - result must be 08:00:00.000

Comment: Do you mean, that the times between 07:58:30.000 and 08:01:30.000 must be rounded to 08:00:00.000? I posted an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take into account seconds as the following:

```
static private DateTime CurrentTime (DateTime now)
{
    return now.Date.AddSeconds((now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds + 90) / 180 * 180);
}
```

Comment: I make Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " is " + CurrentTime(ts.AddSeconds(60)).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));    Console.WriteLine(ts1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " is " + CurrentTime(ts1.AddSeconds(60)).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            Console.WriteLine(ts1.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff") + " is " + CurrentTime(ts2.AddSeconds(60)).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")); And get: 15.02.2012 08:01:00.000 is 15.02.2012 08:00:00.000
15.02.2012 07:59:58.000 is 15.02.2012 08:00:00.000
15.02.2012 07:59:58.000 is 15.02.2012 08:00:00.000

Comment: Dmitry please look at my next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290401/accurate-three-minute-time-timer-intervals

Answer (score 0):

This bit is wrong

```
AddMinutes(((now.Minute) / 3) * 3 - now.Minute)
```

if now.Minutes is 59

59/3 = 19.

19 * 3 = 57

57 - 59 = -2

59 + -2 = 57 (like you are seeing)

Looks like you want to round rather than truncate, so the easiest thing to do would be to add half of 3 minutes to "now".

```
DateTime tmp = now.AddMilliseconds(90*1000);
```

Comment: For example: I have following time value 15.02.2012 07:59:58.000? I want to round this value to nearest three-minute timevalue. And in general I want make in CurrentTime second argument for specify of delta to round, for example if value between 07:59:30.000 and 08:00:30.000 - result must be 08:00:00.000.

Comment: If you add 90 seconds and then use your existing code it should work. There is probably a better way to do it, but I think this will work.

Comment: May be 60 seconds if value between 07:59:30.000 and 08:00:30.000 - result must be 08:00:00.000 ?

Comment: I think it still works. 07:59:45 + 90 seconds = 08:01:15.  mins=1.  1/3 = 0, * 3 = 0, -1 = -1, so that gets you back to 08:00. Try it and see !

Answer (score 0):

To add three minutes to a DateTime you can use the following function which multiplies the number of minutes you want to add by the number of seconds in a minute:

```
private static DateTime AddNMinutes(DateTime dateTime, int numberOfMinutes)
{
   return dateTime.AddSeconds(numberOfMinutes * 60);
}
```

and then call it using:

```
var myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
var myDateTimePlusThreeMinutes = AddNMinutes(myDateTime, 3);
```